# How to get created stored procedures in last 2 weeks?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way I can detect when was a stored procedure created/modified, so I can get a list of what has been altered in the last 2 weeks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `information_schema.routines` in mysql.

ROUTINE_NAME is column name

CREATED is created date

LAST_ALTERED is modified date

```
select ROUTINE_NAME
from information_schema.routines
where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),created) < 14
```

Comment: There is no sys.objects table in MySQL.

Comment: @Pentium10 - Please check my edited answer. That older query was for sql server.

Comment: Please update your answer with the correct query to get only stored procedures modified in last 2 weeks.

Comment: @Pentiun10 - I do not have mysql on my system. So check if the updated query helps you.